# Nested Loop Char[]

Tags: java, loops, nested

Write a loop that displays all possible combinations of two letters where the letters are 'a', or 'b', or 'c', or 'd', or 'e'. The combinations should be displayed in ascending alphabetical order:

aa
 ab
 ac
 ad
 ae
 ba
 bb
 ...
 ee

Here is my code:

```
   Char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

for(int i=0; i < letters.length() ; i++)
{
  for(int ii=0; ii < letters.length() ; ii++)
  {
    System.out.print(letters[i]);
    System.out.println(letters[ii]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? That looks like it should be working perfectly fine, unless there's a syntax error somewhere that I'm not spotting. What's the output?

Comment: Thats what I thought too...heres the error that I keep receiving

Comment: CTest.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  Char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
  ^
  symbol:   class Char
  location: class CTest
1 error

Comment: See Makoto's answer below- and remember, you should include errors like this in your original post, it'll help people out in future questions :)

Answer (score 2):

What is `Char[]`?  It's likely that you meant `char[]` or even `Character[]`, but I'm siding more with the former.  Remember - objects in Java are capitalized.  Primitives aren't.  You may be looking for a primitive array.

It's also the case that an array does not have a method call to `length`.  You may reference it simply by `letters.length`.